# Change TopoJSON to Texas Counties

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I'm pretty new to topoJSON and am using the below D3 bl.ocks tutorial to build a map of Texas.

http://bl.ocks.org/darrenjaworski/5874214

I've converted my Texas county shapefiles to topoJSON, and now I'm having trouble getting just Texas' counties on my screen. I think it's to do with the following lines...

```
d3.json("finaloutput.json", function(error, ok) {
var counties = topojson.feature(ok, ok.objects.county);

//counties
svg.append("g").attr("class", "county").selectAll("path").data(counties.features).enter().append("path").attr("d", path).style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.properties.belowfpl);
});

//county borders
svg.append("path").datum(topojson.mesh(ok, ok.objects.county, function(a, b) {
    return a !== b;
})).attr("class", "county-border").attr("d", path);

//state borders
svg.append("path").datum(topojson.mesh(ok, ok.objects.county, function(a, b) {
    return a === b;
})).attr("class", "state-border").attr("d", path);
```

What's the easiest way to get Texas counties up instead of Oklahoma'?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite clear, I take it that `finaloutut.json` now contains Texas counties from your shapefile (consequently `ok` contains Texas, not Oklahoma data). But you are still getting other state's counties drawn as well? Or are you unable to draw Texas at all? If you can you share `finalouput.json` it would aid in an answer.

Comment: I figured it out. It was merely targeting the wrong field in the actual topoJSON. So I changed "d3.json("finaloutput.json", function(error, ok) {
var counties = topojson.feature(ok, ok.objects.county);" to "d3.json("finaloutput.json", function(error, tx) {
var counties = topojson.feature(tx, tx.objects.cb_2016_us_county_500k-1);